# Python 2.7: Extract values from same dictionary in multiple functions

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary which is going to be passed to multiple functions. In each of the functions, I need to extract all the values of the dictionary.

For example,

```
def foo(mas_details):
    # Extract mas details
    if 'ip' in mas_details.keys():
        mas_ip = mas_details['ip']
    else:
        logger_object.critical("MAS IP not provided!")
        return False
    if 'username' in mas_details.keys():
        mas_username = mas_details['username']
    else:
        mas_username = 'root'
    if 'password' in mas_details.keys():
        mas_password = mas_details['password']
    else:
        mas_password = 'root'
    if 'protocol' in mas_details.keys():
        mas_protocol = mas_details['protocol']
    else:
        mas_protocol = "http"
    if 'timeout' in mas_details.keys():
        mas_timeout = mas_details['timeout']
    else:
        mas_timeout = 120
```

I have about 15 functions where I will be passing this `mas_details` dictionary. However, extracting the values in each function makes the code repetitive.

I want to put the extraction of the values into a function in itself. However, if I do that, the variables won't be accessible in the parent functions, unless I make all the variables `global`.

What is the best way of going about this?

Comment: `return` the extracted values as a tuple?

Comment: Do you actually use all the 15 variables in all the functions?

Comment: Look into wrapping those functions with a decorator that handles the dictionary part

Comment: @BasicWolf, I have only one dictionary. I have 15 functions, and about 5-6 variables in the dictionary. I use all the keys of the dictionary in each of the 15 functions.

Comment: Is it necessary to make them as 15 separate variables? Can you modify your code so that those functions will access a cleaned dict instead?

Comment: The dictionary has about 5-6 keys, and all of them are needed in all functions. That cannot be modified.

Comment: Gary is trying to say that you could define a function that makes all those checks, but instead of assigning the values to variables, you could add them to a new dictionary.  If it then returned the cleaned dictionary, your functions could use `mas_details = clean(mas_details)` and then `mas_details['protocol']`, for example.  Of course, you would still need that `if` check to see if it returned `False`.

Answer (score 2):

The code can be made a lot smaller:

```
'username' in mas_details.keys():
```

The keys() is superfluous, it's equal to

```
'username' in mas_details
```

But more importantly,

```
if 'username' in mas_details.keys():
    mas_username = mas_details['username']
else:
    mas_username = 'root'
```

is equal to

```
mas_username = mas_details.get('username', 'root')
```

The get function takes a default to use if the key doesn't exist.

But: what you have is some *group of variables* together with some *functionality* that always acts on the variables. That is what we invented the **class** for:

```
class MasDetails(object):
    def __init__(self, mas_details):
        self.username = mas_details.get('username', 'root')
        self.password = mas_details.get('password', 'root')
```

Et cetera. Then just pass in a `MasDetails` instance and use its `.username` property.

```
mas = MasDetails(mas_details)

def foo(mas):
    # use mas.username, mas.password here
```

If you have any functionality that only uses these properties, put it on this class as methods.

In particular, maybe your `foo` function and the 14 others should simply be methods on the `MasDetails` class, then they can use `self.username`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you simply need all the 6 variables in a function, you can destruct the dictionary, i.e.

```
def f1(arg1, arg2, ..., arg6):
   ...

def f2(arg1, arg2, ..., arg6):
   ...

# initialize dictionary
d = {'arg1': 'val1', 'arg2': 'val2', ...}

# fill default values (or use defaultdict with appropriate factory)
d['arg1'] = d.get('arg1', 'default_arg1_value')
d['arg2'] = d.get('arg2', 'default_arg2_value')
...

f1(**d)
f2(**d)
...
```

This would give you an access to variables, without explicit extraction from a dictionary. One of the good practices is to keep the number of arguments limited, so consider initializing the dict with default values once, and then using `**kwargs` and extracting the *required* values manually, in case the number of arguments grows.

```
# 1. Initialize dictionary
# 2. Fill default values
# 3. Use with kwargs:

def f(**kwargs):
    arg1 = kwargs['arg1'] # at this point you are SURE, that there is a value
```